# Snort/Barnyard2 Wont compile on Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu

Tags: security, raspberry-pi, snort

I've been following this [Guide](https://s3.amazonaws.com/snort-org-site/production/document_files/files/000/000/065/original/Snort_2.9.7.x_on_Ubuntu_12_and_14.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA&Expires=1452054250&Signature=cc4SzcQAWiPqHgAvlyukpcclQys%3D) to install snort and barnyard. When I try to configure barnyard I get this error.

```
/usr/local/include/dnet.h:22:23: fatal error: dnet/sctp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <dnet/sctp.h>

compilation terminated.
```

When reviewing the document I have all the dependencies. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by copying the dnet folder from libdnet-master/include source I previously compiled to the root of the barnyard2 folder and make completed successfully.

All the dependencies I had to download for barnyard were extracted to the barnyard source folder.

```
~/snort_src/barnyard2/libdnet-master/include# cp -R dnet ../../
~/snort_src/barnyard2/libdnet-master/include# cd ../../
~/snort_src/barnyard2# make
```

Comment: Wow. I spent a ton of time trying to figure this out. I really appreciate it.